Build doesn't generate all expected files in a Class Library .NET project
I ran Clean on my solution and now it won't work!
When I try to run Debug I get:

Error (active)    MSB3030 Could not copy the file
"obj\Debug\net8.0\SL.Assets.Core.dll" because it was not
found.    SL.Assets.Core  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets

I've tried to delete both bin and obj so it should recreate them, everything seems fine except for the SL.Assets.Core.dll that isn't there.
This is the output folder after rebuild:

Project:

Output type: Class Library
Target Framework: .NET 8.0

Thanks!

What is SL.Assets.Core? Another project in your solution?

@GoodNightNerdPride yes it's project that should generate the dll file, but it doesn't. I'll update the question with a picture of the output folder

Do you see any errors when you only build SL.Assets.Core? Can you show us the content of SL.Assets.Core.csproj?

Check your build dependencies in Project | Project Dependencies - select each project in turn and ensure that any dependences that project has are ticked.

Thanks for all the tips! I ended up just recreating the project and moved the code over, and now it works again! :)

@SteinLundbeckTech If you solved it that way, it's usually a good idea to perform a diff between the old and new code, so you can see specifically what changed. That will help others who experience the same issue without needing to go to the length of recreating the entire project.

@mason yes that's true. I'll look into it
